# Which variable I have to set in settings.py to redirect the nova services url?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-horizon

I am installing [openstack horizon](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/).

When I check the docs on git hub they mention

The minimum required set of OpenStack services running includes the following:

- Nova (compute, api, scheduler, network, and volume services)
- Glance
- Keystone

But my nova, keystone and glance services are running on other machine.

For example:
Horizon is running on 192.168.1.1 and keystone, nova and glance is running on 192.168.1.2.

```
[root@localhost ~]# keystone service-list
+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
|                id                |   name   |   type   |        description        |
+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| 5cb184a0a6be458e9ae6319d3f592d22 | keystone | identity | Keystone Identity Service |
| 759d0f09bdcc4537bb981de9889b778d | quantum  | network  |      Network Service      |
| 8c3b1ab783fa492ba7d004ec38af7a49 |   nova   | compute  |    Nova Compute Service   |
| c5ca826057a8483bb68aba8dd81b5126 |  glance  |  image   |    Glance Image Service   |
| fd35e426172146008a1b20dd7b2b5f6d |  cinder  |  volume  |       Cinder Service      |
+----------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+

[root@localhost ~]# keystone endpoint-list
+----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                id                | region |                  publicurl                  |               internalurl                |                 adminurl                 |            service_id            |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 12e0810eb2774f8cb437afcdd903c431 |  test  |             http://*.*.*.*:9292/v1          |         http://127.0.0.1:9292/v1         |         http://127.0.0.1:9292/v1         | c5ca826057a8483bb68aba8dd81b5126 |
| 13e767828adc4add92cec572d220508d |  test  |     http://*.*.*.*:8774/v1.1/% (tenant_id)s | http://127.0.0.1:8774/v1.1/%(tenant_id)s | http://127.0.0.1:8774/v1.1/%(tenant_id)s | 8c3b1ab783fa492ba7d004ec38af7a49 |
| 18b1360d5d0e4d1cbfd4a5076c56d30b |  test  |      http://*.*.*.*:8776/v1/%(tenant_id)s   |  http://127.0.0.1:8776/v1/%(tenant_id)s  |  http://127.0.0.1:8776/v1/%(tenant_id)s  | fd35e426172146008a1b20dd7b2b5f6d |
| 244a4f0323f94017a9de913090811523 |  test  |            http://*.*.*.*:5000/v2.0         |        http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0        |          http://*.*.*.*:35357/v2.0       | 5cb184a0a6be458e9ae6319d3f592d22 |
| f98ebb649df54e71a91851cb101af3d6 |  test  |              http://*.*.*.*:9696/           |          http://127.0.0.1:9696/          |          http://127.0.0.1:9696/          | 759d0f09bdcc4537bb981de9889b778d |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Which variable I have to set in `settings.py` to point to that url?

I tried `OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL` but didnt work :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "NOVA_URL" setting. All services (nova, swift, glance, etc.) endpoints are provided by Keystone. Only OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL is required in settings.py.

From the doc:

> Keystone also acts as a **service catalog** to let other OpenStack systems
>   know where relevant API endpoints exist for OpenStack Services. The
>   OpenStack Dashboard, in particular, uses the service catalog heavily and this must be 
>   configured for the OpenStack Dashboard to properly function.

You must define all services in keystone first:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/configuringservices.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Romain to reply. But I already tried, but its not working :(

Comment: You mean that Keystone is already set up and all services are created?
If so, would you mind double check the output of the following keystone CLI commands:
`keystone service-list` and `keystone endpoint-list`

Comment: Then you can check keystone API responses by typing this from your Horizon server:
`$ curl -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "<your username here>", "password": "<your password here>"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://192.168.1.2:35357/v2.0/tokens`

It should return a bunch of information, including endpoints.

Comment: Additionaly, you may create another question which describes your problem: can you acces to login page? Have you seen some errors in apache logs, and so on. Because to the question "Which variable I have to set in settings.py to redirect the nova services url?", the answer is really "There is no setting" because as you can see with the aforementioned keystone API call, endpoints are included in the response.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

To configure horizon to access data from another host you can set `OPENSTACK_HOST` in `openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py`

default value for this constant is

```
OPENSTACK_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
```

if you want to get data from `192.168.1.2` then change it as

```
OPENSTACK_HOST = "192.168.1.2"
```

and restart the horizon it will return data from another host.